# Logging every message to database with Django

Tags: database, django, logging

My app logs correctly to a log file, but I'd love to have access to these logs in the database as well. I tried django-log-db but it's not compatible with Django 1.3. Sentry is overkill because it requires deploying a Sentry server.

Is there a simple Django solution for logging to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python logging module with django.db.backends and custom handler that saves massages to database. But I strongly suggest you to use sentry, you can configure it inside your django project so you don't need to run it as a separate server. It aggregates all messages and makes it very easy to analyze.